How to determine what is using a port
When our tests run in CI, we occasionally see failures caused by java.net.BindException: Address already in use.
In order to investigate this, we would like to be able to execute some code to tell us the process that is using a particular port. We have been told that the command lsof -i :<port> can give us this information, but I've found that I'm only able to get any information in some circumstances.
For example, when I try using lsof while using a port myself, using this code (run locally, on a mac)
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0)) {
  int port = serverSocket.getLocalPort();
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -i :" + port);
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), UTF_8);
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
  }
}

I find that it outputs the information I want, something like:
COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    91497 fred.flintstone   66u  IPv6 0x1cde46a19e75cdc7      0t0  TCP *:60562 (LISTEN)

However, if I try to get information about ports that are already being used, it gives no information at all. For example, when I try this:
for (int port = 1; port <= 65535; port++) {
  try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {

  } catch (BindException e) {
    System.out.println("Bind exception caught for port " + port);
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -i :" + port);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), UTF_8);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
  }
}

the only output I see is the ports being used, with no additional information about why.
Bind exception caught for port 53
Bind exception caught for port 5432
Bind exception caught for port 55555
Bind exception caught for port 57506
...

Can anybody tell me what I'm likely to be doing wrong, or suggest an alternative way to get this information? The code needs to work on Linux (for our CI), but ideally it would also work for Max OS X, so I can try it locally.

Bear in mind too that you have to be root to bind to any port <= 1024. Always use ProcessBuilder these days btw

what platforms?

Have you tried executing lsof without -i and parsing the output until you encounter the port number of interest?

I have. Sadly the port which caused the BindException is not in the output.

Have you tried printing, not only the fact that you got a BindException, but also the message contained within that BindException ?  Also, g00se's advice about ProcessBuilder is probably key.

Likely the port is in TIME_WAIT state. You can use netstat -ntap to check it. Apply SO_REUSEADDR socket option before bind() to avoid failure.

@g00se No, you don't have to be a root. You have to have CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability.

Right. And how is that conferred upon a non-root user?

Yep, you're having CI fun.
Reading processes is tricky, specially if you want multiple os-es support.
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), UTF_8);
This doesn't check process.getErrorStream(), which may reveal an error from the process. Also looping from 1 doesn't work on unix without root privilege.

How to answer
